# Is there any way I can add category ID in the URL of a Page in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a page that lists posts from a specific category.

Now I need to add another page which needs to list posts from another category.

I could just create a copy of the template that the working page is using and just change category ID.

But since everything else in the template is the same it would probably be better if both pages use the same page template and the category ID is obtained from the URL.

There is probably a way to achieve this but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Custom Field in the page : `cats` = "1,2,3"

then in page template  :

```
$custom_cats = get_post_custom_values('cats');
$args = array(
    'category'        => $custom_cats[0], //like: 1,2,3
    'orderby'         => 'post_date',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
);
$query = get_posts( $args );
```

This is the same page template.

Comment: You are right. One way to solve the problem would be to add a custom field in the page that will represent category ID and then extract that in the template, but since I only have 1 category per page I would probably have to use get_post_meta() instead of get_post_custom_values.